# Аналитическая функция в триггере mysql

Tags: mysql, триггер

Подскажи, как решить проблему или найти альтернативное решение - на базе одной таблички:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS s.table1(
row_id INT(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
p_id  INT(255) NOT NULL,
Value DECIMAL(20,2) DEFAULT 0);
```

cоздаю триггер:

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER s.t AFTER INSERT 
        ON s.table1
        FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
                INSERT INTO s.table2
                SET r_id = new.p_id,
                Summ = SUM(new.Value) over (Partition by new.p_id);
    END$$
DELIMITER 
;
```

который будет инсертить данные в табличку:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS s.table2(
row_id INT(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
r_id  INT(255) NOT NULL,
Summ DECIMAL(20,2) DEFAULT 0);
```

Суть триггера - в s.table2 будут храниться суммарные данные по каждому s.table1.p_id, чтобы потом извлекать эту информацию во вью, включающую в себя данные из разных таблиц. Триггер облегчит вызов вью - будет по джойну тянуться значение из s.table2.summ, а не вызываться каждый раз аналитическая функция.

Пример s.table1 с данными:

```
ROW_ID VALUE P_ID
1       1   1
2       2   2
3       3   1
4       4   3
5       5   1
6       6   3
```

Что хочу увидеть в s.table2:

```
ROW_ID  R_ID    SUMM
1       1       9
2       2       10
3       3       2
```

Триггер создается, но при инсерте данных в s.table1 получаю ошибку при его выполнении:

```
Error Code: 3593. You cannot use the window function 'sum' in this context.'
```

Comment: А зачем вам нужна оконная функция. Если данные суммарные, то вам надо добавить к тому что хранится, то значение которое вставляют. А если записи еще не было, то не было такого r_id, а значит просто создать запись с данным value. т.е. `INSERT INTO s.table2(r_id, summ) values(new.r_id, new.value) on duplicate key update set summ=summ+new.value` (r_id конечно должно быть уникальным полем)

Comment: Спасибо, ваш совет помог решить проблему.